# не удаляет из базы Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

в таблице mytable (id,resh,text) нужно удалить запись по введенному в первом случае dResh , во втором случае по dText.

эта запись удаляет все нормально

```
case R.id.btnDel:
            db.delete("mytable", "resh" + "='" + dResh + "'", null);
            break;
```

а на эту 0 реакции

```
case R.id.btnDel2:
            db.delete("mytable", "text" + "='" + dText + "'", null);
            break;
```

тут задается dText

```
spinner_text.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // показываем позиция нажатого элемента(в переменную реш заносится значение выбранного элемента)
            dText = spinner_text.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println(dText);
        }
```

база

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TABLE = "mytable";
final String LOG_TAG = "логи";
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    // конструктор суперкласса
    super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- база создана ---");
    // создаем таблицу с полями
    db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE+" ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "resh text,"
            + "text text" + ");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public  ArrayList<String> getAllProvinces(){

    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();


    try
    {

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() >0)

        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Add province name to arraylist
                String resh= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resh"));
                list.add(resh);

            }


        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally
    {
        db.endTransaction();
        // End the transaction.
        db.close();

        // Close database
    }
    return list;


}
```

}

Comment: Т.к. записи отличаются только resh/text и dResh/dText то надо полагать что у вас в dText лежит что-то не то.

Comment: сделал вывод в logcat отображает именно то что нужно

Comment: В таком случае вы описываете невозможную ситуацию. Могу лишь посоветовать отключить InstantRun в студии и перезапустить её и комп и всё что только можно. Ну или попробуйте не из спиннера брать значения а вручную прописать... Где-то у вас ошибка но в приведённом коде её не видат

Comment: может это что то в настройках базы? меня смущает одна запись

Answer (score 1):

все дело в невнимательности

```
    btnDel2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel2);
    btnDel2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

а было

```
    btnDel2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel2);
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо  `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` написать `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()`

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления строки таблицы используйте не сравнение строк в лоб, а LIKE:

db.delete("mytable", "text" + "LIKE '%" + dText + "%'", null);